# Using `console.log` inside of a Worker in Chrome prints the same message twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, web-worker, console.log

Pretty much what the title says. What is weirder is that this only happens when you run the program in a new tab, if you merely refresh the page, there will be only one message for each `console.log`.

Here is `main.js`:

```
const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

Here is `worker.js`:

```
console.log('Foo bar!');
```

Here is `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Web Workers</title>

<style></style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The same is not happening in Firefox. I am using Chrome version 65, what's more odd is that the duplicate message seems to belong to no contexts listed in the "contexts" dropdown, so the only message listed when I try to filter out all console messages aside from ones sent by `worker.js` is the first message, the second message (the duplicate) seems to belong to no contexts.

@bean's answer revealed that there is already a question like this asked (from February 2018, I believe) which has not been answered. If no one answers this question either, I will consider raising an issue in Chrome's development forum/whatever.

Comment: @TarunLalwani localhost, I believe loading files locally does not work in Chrome (for Workers).

Comment: @TarunLalwani local Workers don't work in Chrome, which is why I am accessing the file from `localhost`. If I am not mixing this up with `ServiceWorkers`, Workers only work in HTTPS and `localhost`.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a strange behavior in Chrome, and someone has posted the same issue here
[Console.log double logging from web workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038127/console-log-double-logging-from-web-workers).

However, placing `console.log` directly inside `worker.js` is not a good practice. A web worker runs in a separate thread and listens to the messages posted from `main.js` and take actions accordingly, thus any business logic should be placed inside the `onmessage` event handler. By doing this, you don't have to worry about code being executed twice.

Comment: Yep, this is what I observed, a refreshed page works normally. Anyways, without `console.log`, How are you supposed to debug ?

Comment: You can set breakpoints in the worker javascript file and debug in developer tools. Details here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: I dont think placing `console.log` changes somethings. It's seems the whole worker code is executed twice.

Comment: @T.Todua It's not, it's just getting logged twice (try logging `Math.random()`). Unless you're seeing a different issue.